# Remove the breadcrumbs in wordpress using hook

Tags: php, wordpress

To remove the breadcrumbs I have a solution using css which I have used but I want to remove that using hook instead of css.

```
.breadcrumbs {
  display:none;
}
```

Please let me know the hook to remove the breadcrumbs from all pages.

Comment: WordPress doesn't implement breadcrumbs by default, so you'd need to find out this information from the author of the plugin/theme that puts them there.

Answer (score 0):

Hook to remove breadcrumb is following. Add following code in your theme's `functions.php` file.

```
add_action( 'init', 'd_remove_breadcrumb');
function d_remove_breadcrumb() {
    remove_action( 'storefront_content_top', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 10);
}
```

Comment: But that is for woocommerce

Comment: Oh yes , tell me which theme you are using fir your website?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I could go into its header-page file and just remove/comment it out. 
It already had a do_action there, and if I then used a remove_action in functions.php, it came out an error.

Thank you all for using some time to answer and try to help, which made me think in some other way than I usually do.